# SQL getting max out of count with 2 tables

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables, `Specialization` and I call it table (id, Spec) and `Personal` which I call table2 (id, first_name)

What I want to do is count in table how many times each id is showing there (I do this in the inner loop) and then what I want to do, is show from table2 the name of the id with the maximum count

```
SELECT 
    MAX(subQuery.idCount) AS MaxCount, subQuery.first_name
FROM
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(Table.Specialty) AS idCount
     FROM 
         Specialization as Table, Personal as Table2
     GROUP BY
         Table.ID) AS subQuery
GROUP BY 
    subQuery.Did
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the relationship between  Specialization and Personal tables? for what you show in your question there is none...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: id is a key in both

Comment: Table is a SQL keyword. Don't use it for aliasing tables. use Table1 or simply t1

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your question makes no sense, actually.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, look at your subQuery:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(Table.Specialty) AS idCount
FROM 
    Specialization as Table, Personal as Table2
GROUP BY
    Table.ID
```

You only return one column, `idCount`, but later on, you try to group by `subQuery.Did`, which you don't define anywhere. You also don't filter or expose Table2 anywhere, so it's not needed. This could be fixed if your subquery was something like:

```
SELECT 
    Specialization.ID, COUNT(Specialization.Specialty) AS idCount
FROM 
    Specialization
GROUP BY
    Specialization.ID
```

Then, in the columns selected in the main query, you try to show `subQuery.first_name`, which is also not exposed by the subquery. But, now that you have the number of `specialty` by `id`, you can do an inner join with `Personal` to get the `first_name` of each `id`:

```
SELECT 
    subQuery.idCount, Personal.first_name
FROM  
    (SELECT 
        Specialization.ID, COUNT(Specialization.Specialty) AS idCount
    FROM 
        Specialization
    GROUP BY
        Specialization.ID) AS subQuery
INNER JOIN 
    Personal ON Personal.ID = subQuery.ID
```

Then, it is just a matter of ordering by count and getting the first row, which has slightly different syntax depending on which SQL system you are using. For example, in SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    subQuery.idCount, Personal.first_name
FROM  
    (SELECT 
        Specialization.ID, COUNT(Specialization.Specialty) AS idCount
    FROM 
        Specialization
    GROUP BY
        Specialization.ID) AS subQuery
INNER JOIN 
    Personal ON Personal.ID = subQuery.ID
ORDER BY subQuery.idCount desc
```

However, this can be done with without subqueries and avoiding old-style joins, like @marc_s commented on the question.

With an inner join between `Personal` and `Specialization`, using the ids as the relation you'd have all the rows in `Specialization` with an extra row for the `first_name` of each. Then, you could group by `first_name` to get the number of rows (specializations) for each name.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Personal.first_name
FROM Personal 
INNER JOIN Specialization ON Specialization.id = Personal.id
GROUP BY Personal.first_name
```

Then, you can order by count and return only the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something  like this.

```
WITH cte (Id,IdCount)   AS
      SELECT 
    (  SELECT  ID, 
             COUNT(Specialty) AS IdCount
         FROM 
             Specialization 
         GROUP BY
             ID   )
  select first_name,idCount as MaxCount 
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT per.first_name , idCount , 
            row_number () OVER ( ORDER BY idCount DESC )  rn FROM 
        cte c JOIN Personal per ON c.id = per.id
   ) where rn = 1;
```